# Have Spring boot reload when lib module gets changed on development

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, build

We have 3 modules in our maven project: `module-a`, `module-b` and `module-c`. `module-a` and `module-b` are spring-boot projects, both of them depend on `module-c` which only contains shared code for `module-a` and `module-b`. Here is our process when developing:

- run `mvn install` on module-c to make it available on the local m2 repository.
- then run `mvn spring-boot:run` on `module-a` and `module-b` to deploy spring-boots.

The problem is, whenever we have just a small change on `module-c`, we have to shutdown 2 spring-boots then repeat those 2 steps above which is time consuming and tedious.

We also applied the dependency `spring-boot-devtools` to `module-a` and `module-b` but it only affects on code changed within these 2 modules. And we don't rely on IDE because it usually provides false information with its `autobuild`. And also the version of `module-c` is kept unchanged.

My question is: is it possible to let spring-boot know of changes in library modules and automatically reload/rebuild/restart? We are ok with the `mvn install` on `module-c` just don't want to manually restart spring-boots every time.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: question is vague to me. i'll try to rephrase : do you expect to reload module-c automatically (without code changes or restarting module-a/b) whenever newer version of it is available locally ?

Comment: @kalimba I would expect a way to have module-a/b to reload/rebuild/restart when I run `mvn install` in module-c, I updated the question: "And also the version of module-c is kept unchanged."

Comment: there is no out of box solution for this. you have to create own script to restart module-a/b which you can trigger when `mvn install` is run for module-c. learn about `<build><plugins>` section in `pom.xml` where you can hook up this script.